# Ruby codes works

Tags: ruby

I have the ff array:

```
words =  ['demo', 'none', 'tied', 'evil', 'dome', 'mode', 'live',
          'fowl', 'veil', 'wolf', 'diet', 'vile', 'edit', 'tide',
          'flow', 'neon']
```

And now I am trying to do an anagram like this:

```
["demo", "dome", "mode"]
["neon", "none"]
(etc)
```

So I got this code:

```
result = {}

words.each do |word|
  key = word.split('').sort.join
  if result.has_key?(key)
    result[key].push(word)
  else
    result[key] = [word]
  end
end

result.each do |k, v|
  puts "------"
  p v
end
```

I understand how the word got split and joined but this part here is not clear to me:

```
if result.has_key?(key)
    result[key].push(word)
  else
    result[key] = [word]
  end
```

On the code above it's pretty obvious that result is an empty hash and now we're asking if it has a key of the sorted/joined key via `if result.has_key?(key)` How does that work? Why ask an empty hash if it has a key of the selected key via word iteration?

`result[key].push(word)` also is not clear to me. So is this code putting the key inside the result as its key? or the word itself?

`result[key] = [word]` this one also. Is it adding the word inside the array with the key?

Sorry I am bit confused.

Comment: i love the title of this "question"

Answer (score 4):

The `results` is only empty on the first iteration of the loop. The line

```
if result.has_key?(key)
```

is checking if the `key` created by sorting the letters in the current `word` exists, and in the case of the first iteration when it's empty, yes, it is obviously not there *this time*, but it still needs to check every other time too.

Now, when a particular `key` does not exist yet in `results`, that `key` is added to `results` and a new array containing the current `word` is added as the value for that `key`, in the line

```
result[key] = [word]
```

When a `key` already exists in `results`, that means there is already an array containing at least one `word`, so the current `word` is added into that array, in the line

```
result[key].push(word)
```

Stepping through what's happening:

```
words = ['demo', 'neon', 'dome', 'mode', 'none']

// first iteration of the loop
word = 'demo'
key = 'demo' // the letters in "demo" happen to already be sorted
Is 'demo' a key in results?
results is currently {}
No, 'demo' is not a key in {}
Add 'demo' as a key, and add an array with 'demo' inside
results is now { 'demo' => ['demo'] }

// second iteration
word = 'neon'
key = 'enno'
Is 'enno' a key in results?
results is currently { 'demo' => ['demo'] }
No, 'enno' is not a key in { 'demo' => ['demo'] }
Add 'enno' as a key, and add an array with 'neon' inside
results is now { 'demo' => ['demo'], 'enno' => ['neon'] }

// third iteration
word = 'dome'
key = 'demo'
Is 'demo' a key in results?
results is currently { 'demo' => ['demo'], 'enno' => ['neon'] }
Yes, 'demo' is a key in { 'demo' => ['demo'], 'enno' => ['neon'] }
Add 'dome' to the array at key = 'demo'
results is now { 'demo' => ['demo', 'dome'], 'enno' => ['neon'] }

// ... and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that help you figure this stuff out on your own. Here's an example using [Seeing Is Believing](https://github.com/JoshCheek/seeing_is_believing) with vim:

```
words =  ['demo', 'mode']

result = {}

words.each do |word| # => ["demo", "mode"]
  key = word # => "demo", "mode"
        .split('') # => ["d", "e", "m", "o"], ["m", "o", "d", "e"]
        .sort # => ["d", "e", "m", "o"], ["d", "e", "m", "o"]
        .join # => "demo", "demo"
  result  # => {}, {"demo"=>["demo"]}
  if result.has_key?(key)
    result[key].push(word) # => ["demo", "mode"]
  else
    result[key] = [word] # => ["demo"]
  end
  result  # => {"demo"=>["demo"]}, {"demo"=>["demo", "mode"]}
end

result.each do |k, v| # => {"demo"=>["demo", "mode"]}
  puts "------"
  p v
end

# >> ------
# >> ["demo", "mode"]
```

Other tools I'd use are Irb and Pry.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have answers that provide good explanations of your problem, I would like to present some more Ruby-like approaches that could be used. All of these methods create a hash `h` whose values are arrays of words that are anagrams of each other, which can be extracted from the hash by executing `h.values`.

**Use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-sort)**

This is arguably the most direct approach.

```
words.group_by { |w| w.each_char.sort }.values
  #=> [["demo", "dome", "mode"], ["none", "neon"], ["tied", "diet", "edit", "tide"],
  #    ["evil", "live", "veil", "vile"], ["fowl", "wolf", "flow"]]
```

`group_by` produces

```
words.group_by { |w| w.each_char.sort }
  #=> {["d", "e", "m", "o"]=>["demo", "dome", "mode"],
  #    ["e", "n", "n", "o"]=>["none", "neon"],
  #    ["d", "e", "i", "t"]=>["tied", "diet", "edit", "tide"],
  #    ["e", "i", "l", "v"]=>["evil", "live", "veil", "vile"],
  #    ["f", "l", "o", "w"]=>["fowl", "wolf", "flow"]}
```

after which it is a simple matter of extracting the values of this hash.

**Build a hash by appending words to arrays that are the values of the hash**

```
words.each_with_object({}) { |w,h| (h[w.each_char.sort] ||= []) << w }.values
  #=> [["demo", "dome", "mode"], ["none", "neon"], ["tied", "diet", "edit", "tide"],
  #    ["evil", "live", "veil", "vile"], ["fowl", "wolf", "flow"]]
```

When "demo" is passed to the block the hash `h` is empty, so the block variables are assigned values

```
w = "demo"
h =  {}
```

and the block calculation is performed:

```
h[["d", "e", "m", "o"]] ||= []) << w
```

as

```
w.each_char.sort
  #=> ["d", "e", "m", "o"]
```

Ruby first expands this to

```
h[["d", "e", "m", "o"]] = (h[["d", "e", "m", "o"]] ||= []) << "demo"
```

At this point `h` has no keys, so `h[["d", "e", "m", "o"]]` evaluates to `nil`. The expression therefore becomes

```
h[["d", "e", "m", "o"]] = (nil ||= []) << "demo" 
                        = [] << "demo"
                        = ["demo"]
```

Later, when "dome" is encountered,

```
w = "dome"
w.each_char.sort
  #=> ["d", "e", "m", "o"]
```

and since `h` already has this key, the block calculation is as follows.

```
h[["d", "e", "m", "o"]] = (h[["d", "e", "m", "o"]] ||= []) << "dome" 
                        = (["demo"] ||= []) << "dome"
                        = ["demo"] << "dome"
                        = ["demo", "dome"]
```

We obtain

```
words.each_with_object({}) { |w,h| (h[w.each_char.sort] ||= []) << w }
  #=> {["d", "e", "m", "o"]=>["demo", "dome", "mode"],
  #    ["e", "n", "n", "o"]=>["none", "neon"],
  #    ["d", "e", "i", "t"]=>["tied", "diet", "edit", "tide"],
  #    ["e", "i", "l", "v"]=>["evil", "live", "veil", "vile"],
  #    ["f", "l", "o", "w"]=>["fowl", "wolf", "flow"]}
```

after which the values are extracted.

A variant of this is the following.

```
words.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = []}) { |w,h|
  h[w.each_char.sort] << w }.values
```

See the doc for [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) for an explanation, in particular the discussion of *default values* given by a block.

**For each word, merge a hash having a single key into an initially-empty hash**

```
words.each_with_object({}) { |w,h|
  h.update(w.each_char.sort=>[w]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }.values
```

The argument `w.each_char.sort=>[w]` is shorthand for `{ w.each_char.sort=>[w] }`.

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a "resolution" block (here `{ |_,o,n| o+n }`) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes begin merged. See the doc for a description of that block's three keys (the first block variable, the common key, is not used in this calculation, which is why I used an underscore).